# Get Day time according to the timezone of user

Tags: javascript, node.js, date, timezone, google-cloud-functions

I have a firebase cloud function that sends a push notification to my app. I want to send notification only in the day time. 
I am using  moment-timezone and have installed moment-timezone: "^0.5.27" by npm install (moment ^2.24.0 is installed as well)

I'm trying to convert the current date to a different timezone using the following:

```
moment.tz(date, 'CST').format();
```

and it throws this error:

> Moment Timezone has no data for CST. See http://momentjs.com/timezone/docs/#/data-loading/.

In their timezone documentation is mentioned that

> In Node.js, all the data is preloaded. No additional code is needed for loading data.

So why does this message show up? Is there any way by which I can get current time according to the timezone passed dynamically?

Comment: You can do this without a library using *Date.prototype.toLocaleString*, e.g. `new Date().toLocaleString('en-gb',{timeZone:'America/Chicago', timeZoneName:'long'})`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem you are having is due to the value you are giving to the Timezone method.

If you are seeking Central Standard Time, use `'America/Chicago'` instead of `CST`.

Taken from Moment.js [documentation](https://momentjs.com/timezone/docs/):

> Note also that these abbreviations are not globally unique. Below, you
>   can see that both United States Central Standard Time and China
>   Standard Time have the same abbreviation.
>
> moment.tz('2016-01-01', 'America/Chicago').format('z');    // CST

Comment: I only have these abbreviations and UTC offset stored in database by Mobile Applications and I am dynamically getting these values and checking if it is day time or not. Is there any other way to achieve this by Abbreviations or UTC offset.

Comment: @JitenderaKumar - Then I would suggest you change those abbreviations into something that moment.js can recognize. Meaning, instead of saving CST in your database, save America/Chicago. **If my answer helped you, please mark it as such.**

Comment: Also note that not all places in a particular timezone use the same offset rules (such as historic changes and daylight saving), hence the use of representative locations like America/Chicago.